# is document view architecture same as MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-c++

Is  MFC's document view architecture the same as MVC pattern or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) MFC's Document/View architecture is a MVC implementation.

Comment: Your previous link wasn't working because somehow the hyphens in the URL got turned into long dashes.